# Learn to Program - eachEven method example - need help understanding iteration

Tags: ruby, proc

In Chris Pine's Learn to Program book(chapter 10) he uses the following example to explain how ruby changes a bloc into a proc.  So I understand that part although not understanding the iteration..
following is the example/code.

```
class Array
  def eachEven(&wasABlock_nowAProc)

 # We start with "true" because arrays start with 0, which is even.

    isEven = true

    self.each do |object|
      if isEven
        wasABlock_nowAProc.call object
      end

      isEven = (not isEven)  # Toggle from even to odd, or odd to even.
    end
  end
end

['apple', 'bad apple', 'cherry', 'durian'].eachEven do |fruit|
  puts 'Yum!  I just love '+fruit+' pies, don\'t you?'
end

# Remember, we are getting the even-numbered elements
# of the array, all of which happen to be odd numbers,
# just because I like to cause problems like that.

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].eachEven do |oddBall|
  puts oddBall.to_s+' is NOT an even number!'
end
```

Which yields,

```
Yum!  I just love apple pies, don't you?
Yum!  I just love cherry pies, don't you?
1 is NOT an even number!
3 is NOT an even number!
5 is NOT an even number!
```

To me it looks like the eachEven method only calls the `.each` method on the block passed in and then there after set `isEven` to `not isEven`.  Could someone please explain the flow and toggle part of the code..
thanks guys, I truly appreciate all the help I can find.

Answer (score 0):

`self.each` is [`Array#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-each). It is calling `each` on the **array**.

In other words, that block of code will (in the first example) loop through 4 times. In the first loop, `object == 'apple'`; then in the second loop, `object == 'bad apple'`, ...

---

`isEven` is being used as a **flag**. The method you mentioned is **toggling** it:

```
isEven = true         # isEven == true
isEven = (not isEven) # isEven == false
isEven = (not isEven) # isEven == true
isEven = (not isEven) # isEven == false
isEven = (not isEven) # isEven == true
```

---

The end result is that the block of code is being executed on *ever other* element in the array. ("odd" elements, where `isEven == false`, are skipped.)

Here's how I would have written that method (also conforming to the [ruby styleguide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide)):

```
class Array
  def each_even(&block)
    each_with_index do |object, index|
      block.call(object) if index.even?
    end
  end
end

['apple', 'bad apple', 'cherry', 'durian'].each_even do |fruit|
  puts "Yum!  I just love #{fruit} pies, don't you?"
end
```

Comment: Aahh now i see the error in my reasoning.  Thx for showing me the flow. I now understand what's going on there with the 'not isEven' toggle part of the iteration in the method.

Comment: I understand your code and it feels like it is a bit easier to read. Thx for adding it.  I just have one question.  I see that you combined the .each method with the .with_index method. I see that you use an undescore to join them together.  And what about self.  Is that part of your code the same as self.each.with_index

Comment: Aahh again. Googled it.  Looks like each_with_index is a method on its own and differs from .with_index in the sense that it does not take any offset parameters..awesome!

Comment: @codebreeze Yes, that's right. `each_with_index` is a totally separate (although closely related) method to `with_index`. You can only chain ruby methods together with a `.`, not with an underscore! And I removed the `self` simply because it's not needed: there is an *implicit* `self` in ruby when you make method calls like this. (See [the styleguide I linked above](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide): *"Avoid `self` where not required. (It is only required when calling a self write accessor, methods named after reserved words, or overloadable operators.)"*)

Comment: Thx.  Now i understand it all much better.